# read/write a file input and insert a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file

I need to write function which given a text file object open in read and write mode and a string, inserts the text of the string in the file at the current read/write position. In other words, the function writes the string in the file without overwriting the rest of it. When exiting the function, the new read/write position has to be exactly at the end of the newly inserted string.
The algorithm is simple; the function needs to:

1. read the content of the file starting at the current read/write position
2. write the given string at the same position step 1 started
3. write the content read at step 1. at the position where step 2. ended
4. reposition the read/write cursor at the same position step2. ended (and step 3. started)

If the argument file object is not readable or writable, the function should print a message and return immediately without changing anything.
This can be achieved by using the methods file object methods `readable()` and `writable()`.

In the main script:

1- prompt the user for a filename

2- open the file in read-write mode. If the file is not found, print a message and exit the program

3- insert the filename as the first line of the file followed by an empty line

4- insert a line number and a space, at the beginning of each line of the original text.

I'm very confused on how to write the function and main body.
so far I only have

```
def openFile(fileToread):
    print(file.read())


givefile = input("enter a file name: ")
try:
    file = open(givefile, "r+")
    readWriteFile = openFile(file)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File does not exist")
    exit(1)

print(givefile, "\n")
```

which is not a lot.

I need an output like this:

```
twinkle.txt

1 Twinkle, twinkle, little bat! 
2 How I wonder what you're at! 
3 Up above the world you fly, 
4 Like a teatray in the sky.
```

the file used is a simple .txt file with the twinkle twinkle song
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Basic solution

```py
give_file = input("enter a file name: ")


def open_file(file):
    return file.read()


def save_file(file, content):
    file.write(content)


try:
    # Use this to get the data of the file
    with open(give_file, "r") as fd:
        file_content = open_file(fd)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File does not exist")
    exit(1)
    
# change the data
new_content = f'{give_file}\n\n{file_content}'

try:
    # save the data
    with open(give_file, "w") as fd:
        save_file(fd, new_content)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File does not exist")
    exit(1)
```

This should give you the expected result.

#### I asked about the `r+` and how to use it in this case. I got this answer:

> reset the cursor to 0 should do the trick

```py
my_fabulous_useless_string = 'POUET'
with open(path, 'r+') as fd:
  content = fd.read()
  fd.seek(0)
  fd.write(f'{my_fabulous_useless_string}\n{content}')
```

so with your code it's:

```py
give_file = input("enter a file name: ")


def open_file(file):
    return file.read()


def save_file(file, content):
    file.write(content)


try:
    # Use this to get the data of the file
    with open(give_file, "+r") as fd:
        file_content = open_file(fd)
        new_content = f'{give_file}\n\n{file_content}'
        fd.seek(0)
        save_file(fd, new_content)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File does not exist")
    exit(1)
```

#### A suggestion

Don't use function, it hide the fact that a method is used with some side-effects (move the cursor).
Instead, call the method directly, this is better:

```py
give_file = input("enter a file name: ")

try:
    # Use this to get the data of the file
    with open(give_file, "+r") as fd:
        file_content = fd.read()
        new_content = f'{give_file}\n\n{file_content}'
        fd.seek(0)
        fd.write(new_content)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File does not exist")
    exit(1)
```

#### Or, with the basic solution and functions

```py
def open_file(path):
    with open(path, "r") as fd:
        return fd.read()


def save_file(path, content):
    with open(path, 'w') as fd:
        fd.write(content)


# get file_name
file_name = input("enter a file name: ")
try:
    # Use this to get the data of the file
    file_content = open_file(file_name)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File does not exist")
    exit(1)
# change the data
new_content = f'{file_name}\n\n{file_content}'
# save the data
save_file(file_name, new_content)
```

Comment: @MMSS19 I edited my answer to provide better solutions and give some advices.